# не уставливается gulp-sass

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

Добрый день
Проблема: не могу установить gulp-sass в готовой сборке gulp. гуглил, пробовал разные варианты.
Ввожу команду npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
По логам ошибка что-то связано с python.
Ссылка на скриншот: https://yadi.sk/i/uNYRyCeg3LXJnE

Я поставил python 
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools - не помогло
Не устанавливается именно gulp-sass, другие пакеты устанавливаются.

Если я создам свою сборку, gulp-sass установится, не работает только с готовой сборкой, что-то там где-то прописано
Ссылка на сборку: 
https://github.com/amir73911/project-template (если кто-то захочет посмотреть)
Обязательно надо работать с этой сборкой

Помогите, как решить